# Enable IndentGuide Eclipse plugin in java files

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

To install indentation in Eclipse I dropped [this IndentGuide jar](https://github.com/kiritsuku/IndentGuide/blob/master/pdt_tools.indentGuide.updateSite/plugins/jp.sourceforge.pdt_tools.indentGuide_1.4.1.jar) in the dropins folder (I couldn't install it in the "Install Software..." option as it's not available any longer).

I restarted Eclipse and I see the IndentGuide customization screen, but java does not show in available content types:

[image]

The indentation works fine in text extensions, but does not work for java. I looked at the eclipse/configuration folder but couldn't find anything. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
This is what I see under Text > Java:

[image]

Comment: The links on the mentioned GitHub project are outdated: new location of the [website](http://kiritsuku.github.io/IndentGuide/) and the [update site](https://kiritsuku.github.io/IndentGuide/update/). In _General > Content Types_ preferences, do you have _Text > Java Source File_? Please show the expanded instead of the collapsed content types tree with the check boxes.

Comment: Yes, expanding Text I can see Java Source File, however there's no indentation in Java files. I installed the plugin from the update site you sent me, but the problem persists. I'm using Eclipse 2019-06, too new, that shouldn't be the problem as it works for text files.

Comment: please see update

Comment: It worked after changing preferences and saving....

Comment: Great, then the problem's solved, right? Will you then give yourself an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update preferences to make it work with Java files